# Sort order when using ll

Tags: 16.04, command-line, files, directory, ext4

Is there a way to set the sort order of the files and directories when using the `ll` command? I have two 16.04.5 servers with two `ext4` drives. One folder exists on both drives containing the same files. When using `ll` on both servers the sort order is not the same (`ls -l` has the same result):

`ll` on server a:

```
Alex.txt
iBoy.txt
Immatriculation.txt
Radius.txt
WonderWoman.txt
```

`ll` on server b:

```
Alex.txt
Immatriculation.txt
Radius.txt
WonderWoman.txt
iBoy.txt
```

So the difference is the file `iBoy.txt`. Is there a way to figure out why this file is not located between `Alex.txt` and `Immatriculation.txt` like on server a?

**EDIT 1:**

As requested, here are the locales of both systems.

`locale` on server a:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

`locale` on server b:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: See also the [`ls` info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls`' sort order is defined by your locale's collation setting. You can easily check this with the `locale` command:

```bsh
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Important for sorting is the `LC_COLLATE` value. In my example above, it would sort according to the rules for `en_US.UTF.8` localization, which would sort file names case-insensitive and seems to ignore punctuation characters.

You can temporarily override your global settings with an environment variable. E.g. the `C` locale/collation would sort by the raw ASCII value, so all uppercase letters are before lowercase.

```bsh
LC_COLLATE=C ll
```

Comment: I tried that, but actually `ls` doesn’t acknowledge `LC_COLLATE` but only `LC_ALL` – oh wait, but with an empty `LC_ALL` it does work: `LC_ALL= LC_COLLATE=C ll`

Comment: @dessert `LC_COLLATE` is responsible for sorting. `LC_ALL` overrides all other `LC_*` values though if it is set, so if changing `LC_COLLATE` has no effect, I assume you have `LC_ALL` set to something else at the same time? When you just check the output of `locale`, `LC_ALL` should be empty.

Comment: Alright, thanks both of you! I found out that I had the German locale "kind of" installed, so I installed it ***again*** with `sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8` followed by `sudo update-locale` and it now works perfectly.